# How do I replace space with - in $raw_results in php,mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have search in my website and I want when query is entered 
 the link will be `$results['title']`  but it will have replaced space with -

line:
    `web = str_replace(' ','-',$results['title']);`

I want this:

```
this-is-a-example.php
```

**Here is full code:**

```
$query = $_GET['query'];
$title = $raw_results['title'];
$web = str_replace(' ','-',$results['title']);

$min_length = 1;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`text` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`link` LIKE '%".$query."%') ") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

    echo "<a href='https://example.com/".$web.".php'><h3>".$results['title']."</h3></a><br>";

    echo "<p>".$results['title']."</p>";
        }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
```

When I try open link it just runs /.php . 
 Thanks for every reply

Comment: You can't do this the way you have written it. You need to move line `$title = $raw_results['title']; $web = str_replace(' ','-',$results['title']);` into your `while` loop.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your query result returning multiple rows, you need to put `$web` under `while` loop.

Also each file name should be in lowercase, I've used `strtolower` to convert it to lowercase.

Try below code:

```
$query = $_GET['query'];
$title = $raw_results['title'];

$min_length = 1;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`text` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`link` LIKE '%".$query."%') ") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

            $web = strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$results['title']));

            echo "<a href='https://example.com/".$web.".php'><h3>".$results['title']."</h3></a><br>";

            echo "<p>".$results['title']."</p>";
        }

    } else { 
        echo "No results";
    }

} else {
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
```

Comment: "_Try This_" answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do a poor job of educating the OP and thousands of potential researchers.  Everytime you post an answer, please include some explanation about how your solution works and why it is a good idea.  Please improve your answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks for suggestion. I've tried to improve my answer. I'll keep it in mind for each my next post.

Comment: Thank you for improving.  I'm not trying to boss you around, I just want to help make SO a better site for learning.